How to Dynamically Change Layout of Initial Screen After Returning from another Activity in Android?
In my Android application, I have an Home Page with a "Register" button that takes the user to a registration screen(new activity). After completing the registration the user returns back to the home page and I want to dynamically change the layout of the initial screen to display a welcome message and have them enter some more data.
To provide better clarity, here's the desired flow:

Home Page: This screen contains a "Register" button, as well as a welcoming interface(step1).
Registration Screen: Users are directed here upon clicking the "Register" button, where they input their details(step2).
Post-Registration Update: After completing registration and returning to the Home Page, the layout dynamically updates to display a personalized welcome message and a few more widgets(step3).

I've experimented with using intents and startActivityForResult(), but I'm unsure how to proceed with updating the layout based on the result.

why don't you use screen changing instead of changing layout? For example: Intro screen where you have "Register" button, click on button you see your registration screen and when you finish registration just open home screen where you can show a personalized welcome message and etc.
So you don't need to change the layout, just the screen.
A->B->C;
A- Screen with "Register" button;
B- Registratrion screen;
C-Home screen

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
